# GatsbyJs update provider value from onRouteUpdate

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using a provider for holding global location using gatsby's browser API for accessing location by consumer in other components. The problem is i can't change the global location from `onRouteUpdate`, Here is my code:

#### gatsby-browser.js:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

import Provider,{ appContext } from './provider';

export const onRouteUpdate = ({ location, prevLocation }) => {

    console.log('new pathname', location.pathname)
    console.log('old pathname', prevLocation ? prevLocation.pathname : null)

    // wanna set the new location for provider to use in other pages
    // this code does not work
    return(
        <appContext.Consumer>
        {context => {
            context.changeLocation(location.pathname)
        }})
        </appContext.Consumer>
    )

}
```

#### Provider.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { globalHistory as history } from '@reach/router'

export const appContext = React.createContext();

const Provider = props => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(history.location);

  return (
    <appContext.Provider value={{
      location,
      changeLocation: (newLocation)=> {setLocation({location:newLocation}); console.log('changing')}
    }}>
      {props.children}
    </appContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default Provider;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onRouteUpdate` isn’t expected to return React nodes, and so the React element you’re returning isn't going to be evaluated like you’d expect.

Since you’re only looking to store the current page, you don’t actually need to do anything manually `onRouteUpdate` because this functionality is available out-of-the-box with Gatsby.

```
// gatsby-browser.js
import React from "react"
import { appContext } from "src/provider"

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => (
  <AppContext.Provider value={{ location: props.location }}>
    {React.createElement(element, props)}
  </AppContext.Provider>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem solved, Lets suppose i had another variables too that should change when route change, So is it possible to change a provider value from that function?

Comment: @RezaRamezanpour Not directly, but you could do one of the following: 1) export a global function from the parent of your context provider that allows changing the state that is provided; or 2) emit a custom event on `document` that you listen for in your context provider wrapper.

Comment: @coreyward number 1 solved my issue with dispatching actions from the store on route update